# Scripting WebApp VNET integration with Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I can use the azure portal to add a web app to a virtual network for communications between various services hosted on it. However I have everything else in the environment scripted via Powershell and would like to automate the WebApp/VNET integration too.

I have read the following article so far:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

However that is just how to do it via the portal. I am thinking that the Set-AzureRMWebApp cmdlet is the right thing to use, but i can't see any parameters that might help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652487.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported, we have it on our to-do list, unfortunately I don't have an eta right now

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a way to do this using a PS modules. However functionality has now been added to azure CLI. So you can just involke this from a script.

```
az webapp vnet-integration add -g "resource group name" -n "app service name" --vnet "vnet name" --subnet "subnet name"
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need an existing VNet with P2S configured as per my post at http://www.techdiction.com/2016/01/12/creating-a-point-to-site-vpn-connection-on-an-azure-resource-manager-virtual-network/

Then use the below PowerShell to connect the AppService to the VNet using P2S VPN:

```
$subscription_id = "<Subscription_ID>"
$NetworkName = "<Network_Name>"
$location = "<Region>"
$netrgname = "<Resource_Group_VNet_is_in>"
$AppServiceName = "<AppService_Name>"
 $props = @{
      "vnetResourceId" = "/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourcegroups/$netrgname/providers/Microsoft.ClassicNetwork/virtualNetworks/$NetworkName";
      "certThumbprint"= "<Client_cert_thumbprint>";
      "certBlob"= "<Base64_Cert_Data>";
      "routes" = $null;
      }

New-AzureRMResource -ResourceName "$AppServiceName/$AppServiceName-to-$NetworkName" -Location $location  -ResourceGroupName MarcusWebsites -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections -PropertyObject $props -ApiVersion "2015-08-01" -force
```

You can configure custom routes if you require by modifying the routes property. Let me know how you get on and if it resolves the situation please mark this post as the answer.

Marcus