# VNet not found when attempting to create VNET integration via azureRM

Tags: powershell, vnet, azure-rm

I am attempting to configure the VNET of an app service. I am attempting to do this via a powershell script. I have been using the same powershell script for over a year and it has suddenly stopped working without any modifications to the script. The link that is failing is as follows:

```
$propertiesObject = @{
     "vnetResourceId" = "/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($vnetToaddResGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$($vnetToAdd)"
}

New-AzureRmResource -Location $location -Properties $propertiesObject -ResourceName "$($WebApp)/$($vnetToAdd)/primary" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections/gateways" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroup -Force
```

This then results in the following error:

```
New-AzureRmResource : {"Code":"NotFound","Message":"Cannot find Vnet with name
VNet-EUDEV02.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Cannot find Vnet with name
VNet-EUDEV02."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"51004","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with
name {1}.","Parameters":["Vnet","VNet-EUDEV02"],"Code":"NotFound","Message":"Cannot find Vnet with name
VNet-EUDEV02."}}],"Innererror":null}
At C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Repos\devops-scripting\andre-script-remake\clusterswap.ps1:66 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResource -Location $location -Properties $propertiesOb ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourc
   eCmdlet
```

This is strange as I have checked the VNET exists, and also checked the the resource group, and have tried numerous other Vnets.

How can I add VNet integration via a powershell command using azureRM?

Answer (score 0):

This command is trying to use Gateway-required VNet Integration. I guess you already have a gateway provisioned and intend to use it.

Looking at the command, one thing which stands out is this parameter

> -ResourceName "$($WebApp)/$($vnetToAdd)/primary"

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195389/4706703) post on how to do this.

Additionally, there is a PS script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-an-app-in-Azure-ab7527e3) that can be used to provision the VPN gateway and then configure it with the Web App.

BTW, there are other options to consider.

1. If your resources are in the same region, then you could avoid additional costs associated with Gateways, by using [Regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). This is super easy to setup. The CLI is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#automation)
2. There is also [NAT Gateway](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/11/15/web-app-nat-gateway.html). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quickstart-create-nat-gateway-portal) for provisioning NAT Gateways

HTH